# How to visit an array in llvm ir?

Tags: arrays, c, compiler-construction, llvm, llvm-ir

I am confused about how llvm visits an array.

For a 2-dimension array, like

```
int a[5][5];
int func1(){
    return a[1][2];
}
```

The translated llvm-ir is

```
@a = global [5 x [5 x i32]] zeroinitializer, align 16
define i32 @func1() #0 {
entry:
  %0 = load i32, i32* getelementptr inbounds ([5 x [5 x i32]], [5 x [5 x i32]]* @a, i64 0, i64 1, i64 2), align 4
  ret i32 %0
}
```

I think what had been done is to first use index 1 to fetch the inner dimension "[5 x i32]" and then use index 2 to fetch "i32".

But when a 2-dimension array as a function parameter(or array pointer), then things go weird

```
int func2(int a[][5]){
    return a[2][3];
}
```

```
define i32 @func2([5 x i32]* %a) #0 {
entry:
  %a.addr = alloca [5 x i32]*, align 8
  store [5 x i32]* %a, [5 x i32]** %a.addr, align 8
  %0 = load [5 x i32]*, [5 x i32]** %a.addr, align 8
  %arrayidx = getelementptr inbounds [5 x i32], [5 x i32]* %0, i64 2
  %arrayidx1 = getelementptr inbounds [5 x i32], [5 x i32]* %arrayidx, i64 0, i64 3
  %1 = load i32, i32* %arrayidx1, align 4
  ret i32 %1
}
```

I don't know if my understanding is correct.

It seems that the location of "a" is loaded to %0 and currently %0 has type "[5 x i32]*"

```
%0 = load [5 x i32]*, [5 x i32]** %a.addr, align 8
```

Then use "%0" to visit the outer dimension of "a", but now "%0" is considered to be "[5 x i32]", and "%arrayidx" will have type "i32".

```
%arrayidx = getelementptr inbounds [5 x i32], [5 x i32]* %0, i64 2
```

Then it is more strange, "%arrayidx" is still considered as "[5 x i32]", but it is actually "i32"

```
%arrayidx1 = getelementptr inbounds [5 x i32], [5 x i32]* %arrayidx, i64 0, i64 3
```

How to explain it? And how to use API like `Builder.CreateInBoundsGEP(type, array, Idxs);` to generate it? It seems impossible because I tried

```
// type is "[5 x i32]" and array also has a type of "[5 x i32]", inorder to generate the same ir 
// as %arrayidx = getelementptr inbounds [5 x i32], [5 x i32]* %0, i64 2
auto arrayidx = Builder.CreateInBoundsGEP(type, array, Idxs)

// but now arrayidx is "i32" and now type and the type of arrayidx is not match
auto arrayidx1 = Builder.CreateInBoundsGEP(type, arrayidx, Idxs)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
%arrayidx = getelementptr inbounds [5 x i32], [5 x i32]* %0, i64 2
```

Both `%0`and `%arrayidx` are `[5 x i32]*`.

`B = getelementptr <type>, <type>* A, i64 idx0` is something like `B = &A[idx0]`.

```
%arrayidx1 = getelementptr inbounds [5 x i32], [5 x i32]* %arrayidx, i64 0, i64 3
```

`%arrayidx1` is `i32*`.

`C = getelementptr <type>, <type>* B, i64 idx0, i64 idx1` is something like `C = &B[idx0][idx1]`